# How to hide ads with media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am adding mobile css to my webpage, and I'm trying to hide a left vertical column ad to fit mobile platforms.  How can I do this? I tried to hide the ad, but have been unsuccessful

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="leftcolumn"><div id="nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://results.htm">Results</a></li>
        </ul> 

    <p>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_width = 160;
    google_ad_height = 600;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script src="http://test.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    </p></div> </div>

    <!-- end of nav -->  
    <!-- end of leftcolumn -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#leftcolumn { float:none;
              width: 120%;
              letter-spacing:0.1em;
}
script #leftcolumn {
    display:none
}
```

Comment: u hv to try remove this div on mobile view
$('#leftcolumn').remove();

Comment: If this is about actual Google AdSense, then I’m pretty sure their terms forbid you from messing with the apperance of their ads in _any_ way.

Comment: @CBroe I have edited the post to reflect just how to hide the advertisment

Comment: @CBroe I understand you are allowed to use Google's "responsive ads" which resize themselves and don't require hiding. See this article: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to the ad: currently i have added `adblock`

```
<div id="leftcolumn"><div id="nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://results.htm">Results</a></li>
        </ul> 

    <p id="adblock">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_width = 160;
    google_ad_height = 600;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script src="http://test.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    </p></div> </div>
```

Now,

```
@media (max-width : 480px) {
    #adblock {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

If you want to hide the vertical column itself:

```
@media (max-width : 480px) {
   #leftcolumn {
      display: none;
    }
}
```